# Quick One-click Order functionality

Tags: magento

Right off the bat, Magento platform requires customers to register an account, add their items to the cart and then check it out. How would I go about removing all of this hassle and implement a one-click order functionality without the need of adding to cart?

To demonstrate, take a look at this link: http://royalglasses.pk/index.php/brands/ray-ban-pakistan/ray-ban-aviator-exclusive.html

On the right side, you will see a "Order Form" section, where customers can input their information and check out and they do it for each individual item they wish to purchase.

I should also mention that the store only ships inside the city and there's only one method of payment, that is, "cash on delivery". Therefore the last two steps in usual Magento transaction (shipping method and payment information) render useless for my client.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with following the Magento logic without breaking its normal flow. A code snippet from a script I did before describes the full checkout process for guest customer. Yours should not be much different. Please don't copy and paste, review the code and tweak it to your needs.

```
//Load the product from the posted form and cart and quote models.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load((int) $_POST['product_id']);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$quote = $cart->getQuote();

//Add the product to the cart and set the session to updated
$params = array('product' => $product->getId(), 'qty' => (int) $_POST['qty']);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

//Load variables needed for the order process and transaction object to save the order.
$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
$reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);

//Load the order model and set some default values
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setQuoteId($quote->getId())
                ->setGlobalCurrencyCode('USD')
                ->setBaseCurrencyCode('USD')
                ->setStoreCurrencyCode('USD')
                ->setOrderCurrencyCode('USD');

//Assign customer as guest, $customer is array from $_POST['customer']      
$order->setCustomerEmail($customer['email'])
                ->setCustomerFirstname($customer['firstname'])
                ->setCustomerLastname($customer['lastname'])
                ->setCustomerGroupId(0)
                ->setCustomerIsGuest(1);

//Prepare billing address and add it to the order
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
                ->setCustomerId(0)
                ->setCustomerAddressId(0)
                ->setCustomerAddressId(0)
                ->setFirstname($customer['firstname'])
                ->setLastname($customer['lastname'])
                ->setStreet($customer['address'])
                ->setCity($customer['city'])
                ->setCountryId($customer['country_id'])
                ->setPostcode($customer['postcode'])
                ->setTelephone($customer['phone']);
$order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

//Prepare shipping address and add it to the order, then set the shipping method
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
                ->setCustomerId(0)
                ->setCustomerAddressId(0)
                ->setCustomerAddressId(0)
                ->setFirstname($customer['firstname'])
                ->setLastname($customer['lastname'])
                ->setStreet($customer['address'])
                ->setCity($customer['city'])
                ->setCountryId($customer['country_id'])
                ->setPostcode($customer['postcode'])
                ->setTelephone($customer['phone']);

//Add the shipping address and the shipping method.             
$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
                ->setShippingMethod('yourshipping_code')
                ->setShippingDescription('Your shipping description');

//Add your payment method.
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
                                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                                    ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
                                    ->setMethod('cod'); //cod is Cash on Delivery
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);


//Loop through the items in the quote, create order item and add it to the order, you have only one product, so it will add only one order item.
foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) 
{
    $_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
    $rowTotal = $item->getCalculationPrice() * $item->getQty(); 
    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                    ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                    ->setProductId($_prod->getId())
                    ->setProductType($_prod->getTypeId())
                    ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                    ->setTotalQtyOrdered($item->getQty())
                    ->setQtyOrdered($item->getQty())
                    ->setName($_prod->getName())
                    ->setSku($_prod->getSku())
                    ->setPrice($item->getPrice())
                    ->setBasePrice($item->getPrice())
                    ->setOriginalPrice($item->getPrice())
                    ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
                    ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

//Set the totals
$subTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
$order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
        ->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
        ->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
        ->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);


//First, place the order, then save it.     
$transaction->addObject($order);
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
$transaction->save();
$quote->save();

//Clear the session and the cart.
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
foreach($quote->getItemsCollection() as $_item)
{
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem($_item->getId())->save();
}

//Redirect the user back to where you want.
```